# Bluetooth dongle no device found during scan

Tags: bluetooth, debian, retropie

I want to use my Rpi3 to run retropie and I'm trying to connect a controller with Bluetooth. Using the integrated peripheral I was able to pair it, but the delay was huge (we're talking seconds).

Searching online I found that using WiFi and Bluetooth on the same board can cause issues, so I bought a Bluetooth dongle. The brand is ugreen. I managed to get it working, so the controller is recognized and the Bluetooth service is active and running.

Nevertheless, I can't find any device. When running `bluetoothctl scan on` no device is found. I also enabled pairability and discoverability, but nothing changed.

No clue how to solve it though. Any ideas?

Comment: how is the controller recognized when you can't find any device?

Comment: Because when i open bluetoothctl i read "agent registered; controller <MAC> Pairable:yes"

Comment: isn't the controller the handheld device, and not the Bluetooth dongle? ... `I'm trying to connect a controller with Bluetooth`

Comment: Oh, that you mean. Sorry, maybe unclear. In that case I meant Linux Bluetooth controller, not the joypad controller. So I know the Linux controller for my Bluetooth dongle is recognized, but in turn I can't find any Bluetooth device with that dongle, not even my joypad (controller)